# To_date returning 2 zeros in front of Year wildcard

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert 'Start_date' and 'End_date' to a different format (YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS) which is different from the other format (DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MM).

When I run the command below :

```
Update blarg
Set test1 = 'test',
test2 = 'test',
Start_Date = To_Date('23/07/2015 22:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
End_Date = To_Date('24/07/2015 00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
Where Id = '4';
```

The insert in the database consists of...

```
Start_Date = '0023-07-20 15:22:00'
End_Date = '0024-07-20 15:00:00'
```

I can understand that Oracle probably just can't detect the initial date format and doesn't know where to put the values, but I was curious if you could tell Oracle the original dates wild card and then merge it with the wild card you want to turn it into.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is  what you specified in the code with the format mask :

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Notice that it lobs off the `15` from `2015`

So when you say: '23/07/2015` and use the mask of 'YYYY-MM-DD' , it forces it goes as so:

`23` --> `YYYY` =  `0023`
etc

So to solve, rearrange the literal date to fit into the mask of `YYYY-MM-DD` (Leaving that as exercise for you to learn it : - )

[SQL Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to convert 'Start_date' and 'End_date' to a different format*

You are mis-understanding how `date` (or `timestamp`) columns work:

### `DATE` columns do NOT have "*a format*"

Any format you *see* when selecting your data is applied by the SQL client you are using.

If you want to see the date values in a different format, then just do so when selecting them:

```
select to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as start_date,
       to_char(end_date, ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as end_date
from the_table;
```

If you always want to see dates formatted like that, change the configuration of your SQL client.